# OSGI Gradle Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.opencsv; version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)" Liferay IDE 3

Tags: eclipse, gradle, liferay, osgi, build.gradle

I am trying to use the opencsv library in my project to read some CSV files. I add this dependency properly in gradle and it appears for use in develop time. However during deploy time with OSGI this error appears:

```
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.opencsv;version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
```

Maybe I am loosing the basics. I dig inside jar and in the Manifest autogenerated appears "com.opencsv;version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)" in "Import-Package" entry. I think my `build.gradle` is at fault:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.3.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.util.taglib", version: "2.1.0"
    compile group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "2.0"
    compile group: "javax.servlet", name: "servlet-api", version: "2.5" 
    compile group: "jstl", name: "jstl", version: "1.2"
    compile group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.compendium", version: "5.0.0"    
    compile group: "com.opencsv", name: "opencsv", version: "3.8"

}

version = '1.0.0'
```

I am sure the solution could be easy and stupid but I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will reply myself. I hope this will help for others.

For those kinds of libraries you have to do this things:

- Download your jar and put it in your main/resources.
- In your bundle.gradle of the project add

  ```
  bundle {
  exclude group: 'group.of.package'
  instruction 'Bundle-ClassPath', '.,nameofjar.jar' 
  instruction 'Embed-Transitive', 'true'}
  ```
- Refresh Gradle dependencies
- Remove failing bundle from server.
- Cleand and Build and Deploy.

I hope this works for you. If not try to contact me and try to help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `Import-Package: *; version="0";resolution:=optional` to your bnd file. It solved my problem, I hope it will solve yours too.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you are using the liferay gradle plugin or bnd gradle plugin is to add a `bnd.bnd` file to your module and put this instruction in there

```
Private-Package: \
    <your.package.name>.*,\
    com.opencsv.*
```

This way you don't need the `bundle {...}` block.  Private-package will copy all of the referenced files into your file jar and those classes will be available during your bundles execution.  Here is [more reference on the `Private-Package:` instruction](http://bnd.bndtools.org/heads/private_package.html).